# KitKat "new" Launcher - non English (US) language

Tags: launcher, 4.4-kitkat

I have a Nexus 4. It was updated to KitKat last night.

From what I've gathered from the reviews, I should have a new Launcher. But my phone is still using the old one.

Does anyone know if the launcher is not available for pt-br phones? Or I am missing something?

Thanks!

*Edit*

Forget it. It seems that the new Launcher (and some other stuff) are exclusive to te Nexus 5. :(

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/11/22/psa-what-some-device-owners-wont-see-in-their-kit-kat-update/

Comment: Rather than editing your question, add that extra information as an answer. That will help guide future readers.

Comment: I've considered doing that. But I really wasn't sure. Guess I'll be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it seems the best features (at least for me) will be exclusive to the Nexus 5:

http://www.droid-life.com/2013/11/22/psa-what-some-device-owners-wont-see-in-their-kit-kat-update/

From that list:

- Google Experience Launcher
- Translucent Nav Bar and Notification Bar
- Smart Dialer

That's really a shame!